# Does the fact that $ \lim\limits_{n\to \infty} u_{n+1}-u_n = 0$ implies $u_n$ bounded?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

Assume that $(u_n)_n$ is a sequence of complex number such that

$$\lim_{n\to  \infty} u_{n+1}-u_n = 0$$
Does this implies that $u_n$ is bounded?

I know this result is true if we assume $u_n$ to be Cauchy sequence. 
But having 
$\lim\limits_{n\to  \infty} u_{n+1}-u_n = 0$
seems not to implies that $u_n$ is bounded.
Any counter example?

Comment: That is a typical Example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe $u_n = \ln (n)$ works, no? Let's see.
$$
\ln(n+1)-\ln(n) = \ln\left(\frac{n+1}{n} \right) = \ln \left(1 + \frac{1}{n} \right)
$$
does tend to $\ln(1)=0$ as $n \to \infty$.  Yet, $u_n=\ln(n)$ is unbounded.

Answer (score 4):

Let $u_n$ be the sequence of partial sums of the harmonic series.

Comment: Very nice example.