# show that $x_{n+1}$- $x_n$ $\rightarrow $ 0 and n $\rightarrow \infty$ does not imply cauchy

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, cauchy-sequences

Let $(x_n)_n$ be a sequence of real numbers and consider the following statements

a) $(x_n)_n$ is cauchy

b) $x_{n+1}$- $x_n$ $\rightarrow $ 0 and n $\rightarrow \infty$.

show that a) implies b)

by considering $(x_n)_n =(1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}...+\frac{1}{n})_n$ show that b) does not imply a).

Comment: Have you done those things?

Comment: no i dont know how

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does the fact that $ \lim_{n\to \infty} u_{n+1}-u_n = 0$ implies $u_n$ bounded?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2490814/does-the-fact-that-lim-n-to-infty-u-n1-u-n-0-implies-u-n-bounded)

Answer (score 2):

$x_{n+1}-x_{n}=1/n\rightarrow 0$ but for $n>m$, $x_{n}-x_{m}=\dfrac{1}{m+1}+\cdots+\dfrac{1}{n}\geq\displaystyle\int_{m+1}^{n}\dfrac{1}{t}dt=\log n-\log(m+1)$, in particular, $x_{2m+2}-x_{m}=\log 2$ does not converge to zero as $m\rightarrow\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

I)-Take $$S_n =\sum_{k=1}^n \frac1k \to \infty$$
That is $S_n$ is not Cauchy.

But $$ S_{n+1}-S_n =\frac1n\to 0$$

II)- Also take $$u_n = \sqrt n\to \infty$$That is $u_n$ is not Cauchy. But   $$ u_{n+1}-u_n =\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n} =\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}\to 0$$

III)- $$v_n=\ln n\to \infty$$

and  $$ v_{n+1}-v_n =\ln({n+1})-\ln{n} =\ln\left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)\to 0$$

Answer (score 0):

You are probably having a conceptual block in that the two terms probably seem intuitively equivalent.  But they aren't.

1) $x_{n+1} - x_{n} \to 0$ means that each pair of consecutive terms get close together.  But all the terms in general do not get close together as a whole.  It's still possible that terms that are not consecutive can get very far apart.

A good example of this would be $x_n = \log n$.  Then $\log (n+1) - \log n = \log \frac {n+1}n \to \log 1 = 0$.  The terms get "close together".  But on the whole the terms are completely unbounded.  $\log n - \log m \to ?????$.  $x_{n+1}$ and $x_n$ must be close togeter.  But $x_{n}$ and $x_{n^{500gazillionbillion}}$ do not need to be close together at all.

2) $x_n$ is Cauchy means that to terms get "close together" "as a whole".  It's not just that the consecutive terms $x_{n+1}$ and $x_n$ get close together.  It's that *all* terms $x_n$ and $x_m$ get close together.  As $M$ gets larger then $x_n$ and $x_m$ for $m,n > M$ *must* get close together.  $x_n$ and $x_{n^{500gazillionbillion}}$ *do* have to be close together.

Of course that is informal.

The formal definition of $1$ is:

1 or b)) For any $\epsilon > 0$ there is an $M_{\epsilon}$ so that for all $n > M_{\epsilon}$ then $|x_n - x_{n+1}| < \epsilon$.  The "english translation" of that is "we can get any two consecutive terms as close together as we like" (as close together as $\epsilon$) "by taking terms far enough down in the series" (past the $M_{\epsilon}$th term).

2 or a)) "cauchy" means for any $\epsilon > 0$ we can find an $M_{\epsilon}$ so that for all $n, m \ge M_{\epsilon}$ that $|x_n - x_m| < \epsilon$.  The "english translation" of that is "we can get any two terms *not just the consecutive terms $x_n$ and $x_{n+1}$* but *any two terms* such as $x_n$ and $x_{n^{500gazillionbillion}}$ as close together as we like by taking terms far enough down in the series".

Obviously 2) implies 1).  If any two terms $n, m> M_{\epsilon}$ imply that $|x_n - x_m| < \epsilon$, it we work with two consecutive terms $n, n+1 >M_{\epsilon}$.

But the reverse is not true.

Using my example of $x_n = \log n$, then for any $\epsilon > 0$ and any $n > M$, I can find an $m > n > M$ so that $\log m - \log n = \log \frac mn > \epsilon$ simply by taking $\frac mn > 10^\epsilon$.  Which is always possible no matter *how* large I let $n$ be.  I just have to let $m$ be *much* larger.

......

For some reason, analysis classes don't use my logarithm example[$*$] (probably because an analysis class likes to break things down and rebuild things and doesn't want to use "common scense" knowledge of logariths which they will have to prove later... *after* teaching the concept of cauchy..  Instead they nearly always use the Harmony Series.   $\frac 1 + \frac 12 + \frac 13 + \frac 14 + .....\to \infty$ despite the $\frac 1n - \frac 1{n+1} \to 0$.

Google "Harmonic series" for an explanation why $\frac 1 + \frac 12 + \frac 13 + \frac 14 + .....\to \infty$

This means that for any $M$ we can find a $w$ so that  $\frac 1 + \frac 12 + ........ \frac 1w > M$ and for any $\epsilon > 0$ and $n$ we can find an $m$ so that $\frac 1 + \frac 12 + ..... + \frac 1m > \epsilon + (1 + \frac 12 + ..... + \frac 1n$.

Or in other words $x_m - x_n = (\frac 1 + \frac 12 + ..... + \frac 1m) -(\frac 1 + \frac 12 + ..... + \frac 1n) > \epsilon$.

So $\{x_n\}=\{(1 + \frac 12 + .... + \frac 1n)\}$ is not Cauchy.

====

[$*$]Actually the harmonic series and the natural logarithm are closely related.  $\le x = \int_{1}^x \frac 1x dx\approx \frac 12 + \frac 13 + \frac 14 + .... + \frac 1n$ if $x \approx n$ and $n $ is large enough that taking $dx = \delta x \approx 1$ is reasonable approximation (which it is if $x$ is very  large).

Which gives us a significant hint in proving the harmonic series converges.  $\ln m - \ln n = \ln \frac mn$ which can be arbitrarily large.

So $( \frac 12 + ... + \frac 1m) - (\frac 12 + ... + \frac 1n) = \frac 1n +\frac 1{n+1} + \frac 1{n+2 } + ..... \frac 1m > \frac 1n + \frac  1n + \frac 1n + .... + \frac 1n = \frac {m-n}n = \frac mn - 1$ whih can be arbitrarily large.

Ex.  $\frac 12 + \frac 13 + \frac 14 .... >$

$\frac 12 + (\frac 13 + \frac 14 ) + (\frac 15 + \frac 16 + \frac 17 + \frac 18) + ... + (\frac 1{2^n + 1} + .... + +\frac 1{2^{n+1}} ) + .... >$

$\frac 12 + (\frac 14 + \frac 14) + (\frac 18 + \frac 18 + \frac 18  + \frac 18) + (\frac 1{16} + .... \frac 1{16} + ..... + (\frac 1{2^{n+1}} + ..... + \frac 1{2^{n+1}}) + .... =$

$\frac 12 + \frac 24 + \frac 48 + ..... + \frac {2^n}{2n^{n+1}} + ..... =$

$\frac 12 + \frac 12 + \frac 12 + ....... $

which is unlimited.